# Cual es la funcion correcta de un Pre-loader?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, real-time

He estado buscando como hacerlos en varias paginas, pero en todas las que he encontrado veo que utilizan un tiempo especifico en el cual el pre-loader aparecera, y **mi pregunta** es si **la funcion del preloader es aparecer por un tiempo especifico** o **aparecer en un tiempo variado a la conexion de internet del usuario esperando a que la ultima imagen termine de cargarse**? ya que veo que *mega.nz* utiliza un preloader antes de cargar el archivo.
Y añadiendo otra pregunta es que tan efectivos son los preloader?

Comment: y como aplicar si las imagenes estan como un background-image?

Comment: No confundir Java con JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

un preloader casi en su mayoria se utiliza cuando se hacen llamadas Ajax al servidor, es decir se inicia antes de la llamada y se finaliza cuando el servidor arroja un resultado. Ese es el tiempo el cual debe durar.